# Firebase data not showing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have retrieved data from Firebase regarding name and score. I am being able to see the list view for first name and scores of the data retrieved but for the second data retrieved i can not see no scores or names. When I have debugged the app, I have received this "com.example.gymtastic.SquatScore (fields/setters are case sensitive!)".

```
private ListView listView, listview2;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
DatabaseReference ddatabase;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
List<ScoreProfile> scoreList;
List<SquatScore> squatList;


@Override
protected void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
      ddatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot squatsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    SquatScore squatScore = squatsnapshot.getValue(SquatScore.class);
                    squatList.add(squatScore);
                }
                SquatInfoAddapter squatInfoAddapter =new SquatInfoAddapter(RankT.this, squatList);
                listview2.setAdapter(squatInfoAddapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
               throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        }); // This one doesnt

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rank_t);


        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Bench");

        ddatabase = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Squat");

        databaseReference.orderByChild("userScore").limitToFirst(5);
        ddatabase.orderByChild("userScore").limitToFirst(5);

        squatList = new ArrayList<>();

        scoreList = new ArrayList<>();

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

This is my code. The first value listener displays but for the second one created, it just shows empty list views.

This is my Firebase data that i am retrieving but does not show.

```
 "Squat" : {
    "Jn8SOKDgGRMewEHjVG8LaXoYtrl2" : {
      "suserName" : "ace",
      "suserScore" : "369"
    },
    "mooFelp2soMtDmRlg5IQ6AYpKhO2" : {
      "suserName" : "ACe",
      "suserScore" : "1222"
    }
```

Here is my SquatScore class:

```
public class SquatScore {

    private String SuserName;
    private String SuserScore;
    public SquatScore(){};

    public SquatScore(String suserName, String suserScore) {
        SuserName = suserName;
        SuserScore = suserScore;
    }


    public String getSuserName() {
        return SuserName;
    }

    public String getSuserScore() {
        return SuserScore;
    }
}
```

Comment: First things first: implement `onCancelled`. It's minimum implementation should be: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: Thank you, i have implemented the function within the onCancelled method but can only see figures for the first datasnapshot.

Comment: "the first" and "the second" are really hard to parse here, especially since your code doesn't have `first` or `second`. If one of your reads works, please ensure your code only includes what doesn't work. Also edit your question to include the JSON that you're trying to read (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Thank you, I have edited those changes and made changes to the code by adding comments to which one does work and does not.

Comment: Again: we probably don't need to see the code that *does* work, and adding it just makes the question longer than needed. For the part that doesn't work, if you put a breakpoint on `for(DataSnapshot squatsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){` and run in a debugger, does the breakpoint get hit? If so, does it go into the loop?

Comment: I ran a debug and got a "W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for suserName found on class com.example.gymtastic.SquatScore (fields/setters are case sensitive!)". I tried to figure this out but still do not understand what it means. I have a class exactly like this to store data.

Comment: Without seeing `SquatScore` that's impossible for us to verify, so you'll want to add that to your question. Note that all comments so far are just to get to a [minimal, complete/standalone verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I highly recommend reading that link to be able to move faster.

Comment: Will do, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is:

> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for suserName found on class com.example.gymtastic.SquatScore (fields/setters are case sensitive!)"

If we look at your class that is correct:

- there is no field `suserName`, only `SuserName` with an uppercase `S`.
- there is no setter method for a property called `userName`, which would be called `setSusername`.

Without those, the Firebase SDK has no way to know how to set the value from the `suserName` property in the JSON on to your `SquatScore` object.

To fix this, you'll want to either rename the field to `suserName`, or create the setter method.

Comment: I tried to change the name but did not work. But implementing a setter has worked. Thank you very much.